# Preview hover panel in search results malfunctioning with pptx files

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online, when hovering over pptx files in search results, we are prompted by IE that we need to refresh the webpage. This works very disturbing and refreshing or not, the preview only shows that

> the 'webpage has expired'.

My question would be whether this is SharePoint bug or some setting because some pptx files do show ok while most of them don't. Anyone familiar with this and knows the reason why this is happening? Thanks in advance.